# how to append a element to the div onkeypress function

Tags: jquery, onkeypress

I have a function which only allows alphabetic characters to be entered as follows. I want to append the element to that div when this function triggered

```js
function onlyAlphabets(event) {
  var char = event.which;
  if (char > 31 && char != 32 && (char < 65 || char > 90) && (char < 97 || char > 122)) {

    console.log('only alphebets are allowed');
    console.log($(this).val());
    var div = $(this).closest('div');

    div.append('<i class="fas fa-times"></i>');
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event)" id="lastName">
</div>
```

I tried with above code but I am not able to achieve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `this` in your function doesn't refer to the element that raised the event, due to the use of the outdated `on*` event attribute.

To fix this you can use an unobtrusive event handler. As you've already included jQuery in the page, you can use `keypress()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.only-alpha').keypress(function(e) {
    var char = e.which;
    if (char > 31 && char != 32 && (char < 65 || char > 90) && (char < 97 || char > 122)) {

      console.log('only alphebets are allowed');
      var div = $(this).closest('div');

      div.append('<i class="fas fa-times">X</i>');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control only-alpha" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Following your snippet, instead of using this (because it does not refer to the element), I have done using event.target.

Note that the button supplies to the icon.  Hope it helps.

```js
function onlyAlphabets(event) {
  var char = event.which;
  var div =  $(event.target).closest('div');
  if (char > 31 && char != 32 && (char < 65 || char > 90) && (char < 97 || char > 122)) {

    console.log('only alphebets are allowed');
    console.log($(div).val());
   

    if (!div.find('button').length) {
      div.append('<button>ICON</button>');
    }
    
    return false;
  } else {
  $('button').remove();
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event)" id="lastName">
</div>
```

Comment: yes this also working thank you @Albeis for your response